# How to keep Java code and Junit tests together building with Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a project in which the main source and the test cases for that source are kept in the same package/directory. Each test class is the name of the class which it is testing with "Test" appended on the end. So if I have a Foo.java there will be a FooTest.java right next to it.

My question is, how do I build this project with Gradle? I'd still like to keep the class files separate, i.e. a folder for main classes and a folder for test classes.

Comment: Why don't you simply do the right (and easier) thing and separate the production classes from the test classes?

Comment: Part of the ideology behind gradle is that the build tool should not dictate such decisions but should allow flexibility.

Comment: I know gradle, and I think it should be possible. But why do you make your life harder than it needs to be? I can't think of any good reason not to separate the test classes from the production classes.

Comment: "Gradle welcomes the unexpected" -Hans Dockter, founder of Gradle and Gradleware. To answer your question directly, I am currently evaluating Gradle and I wanted to run into something "unexpected" so I could test if this statement of Hans is true or not. I love the thought of a build tool that is flexible. Is Gradle it?

Comment: You should be able to modify the `main` and `test` SourceSets: set their source directory, exclude *Test.java for the main source set, and include *Test.java for the test source set. See http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet:java%28groovy.lang.Closure%29

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["some/path"]
            exclude "**/*Test.java"
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["some/path"]
            include "**/*Test.java"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to do it, but it also seems to break the Eclipse plugin. Now if I run the eclipse task it puts "some/path" in the sources twice. I was able to work around this with the "whenMerged" function on the eclipse.classpath.file. Which is kinda neat but maybe there was a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: The generated Eclipse setup correctly reflects the Gradle setup. Does it cause any problems?

Comment: Yeah, it causes a problem that reads; "Build path contains duplicate entry: 'src' for project '<project-name>'" I see the classpath entries that are causing the problem and I see that logically it shouldn't be a problem. But eclipse still can't handle it. I'll put my workaround in an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

For reference, here is the code I used to try to get around the Eclipse plugin's classpath issue. Using this in combination with Peter's answer above seems to work.

```
// The following ensures that Eclipse uses only one src directory
eclipse {
    classpath {
        file {
            //closure executed after .classpath content is loaded from existing file
            //and after gradle build information is merged
            whenMerged { classpath ->
                classpath.entries.removeAll { entry -> entry.kind == 'src'}
                def srcEntry = new org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.SourceFolder('src', null)
                srcEntry.dir = file("$projectDir/src")
                classpath.entries.add( srcEntry )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this work for me:

```
eclipse {
   classpath {
      file {
        withXml { 
            process(it.asNode())
          }
      }
   }
}
def process(node) {
  if (node.attribute('path') == 'src/test/java' || node.attribute('path') == 'src/test/resources')
    node.attributes().put('output', "build/test-classes")
  else
   node.children().each {
      process(it)
}}
```