# How to run Kotlin test files side by side with source files?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin

In `node.js` and `jest`, the best practice is to put test file side by side with source files, like

```
|- /main
|  |- index.js
|  |- index.test.js
```

and then just run `jest`. How can we do the same in Kotlin and gradle? I 'd like to have `hello.kt` and something like `hello.test.kt`, and somehow run `kotlin` command line tool to run test.

I have read [kotlin-example](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-examples/tree/master/gradle/hello-world) but they have files in `main` and `test` folders.

P/S: If anyone knows how to also do the same in Swift, that would be great.

Comment: Could you add your build.gradle.

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298886/how-to-keep-java-code-and-junit-tests-together-building-with-gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a best practice when working with Kotlin and Gradle you should separate your productive code from test code in different directories and the class to be tested and the test should be in the same package (to have access to package visible restricted methods during tests and easily understand the package layout). You can find this [guideline in the Gradle user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:separate_test_type_source_files). And the [same applies to Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html):

So your layout should follow:

```
src
├── main
│   └── kotlin
│       └── packagename
|           └── Hello.kt
└── test
    └── kotlin
        └── packagename
            └── HelloTest.kt
```

Following these conventions makes it easy to execute the tests with `$gradle test` and every expirienced Java/Kotlin/Gradle/Maven developer will easily understand your project organization.